# How to get result of stored procedure, through web api i have complex type return type?

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-web-api2

I created `model` and `context` through `DB first approach` and have written `stored procedure` in which I have performed `joins` too so my `result row` is not of a standard table. I understand that's why `Entity Framework` creates complex types of return types. So now I need to call the stored procedure in `controller` using `HttpGet` method.

```
This is code Generated by Entity Framework in Context class.

public virtual ObjectResult<flights_on_date_Result> 
flights_on_date(Nullable<System.DateTime> dates, string source, string dest)
    {
       '''''''
       '''''''
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<flights_on_date_Result>("flights_on_date", datesParameter, sourceParameter, destParameter);
    }
```

In Controller i do this:

```
[HttpGet("{dates}/{src}/{dest}")]
    public ActionResult<ObjectResult<flights_on_date_Result>> Flights_on_date(DateTime dates,string src,string dest)
    {
        return _context.flights_on_date(dates, src, dest);
    }
```

I expect a result of multiple rows in json format. I am sending data from the postman and through the browser it returns 404 not found code in both.

Comment: Can you share how do you call your controller? The URL

Comment: can you provide the url you are using  to call your web api ?

Comment: localhost:port/api/controller?dates=2019/11/08&src=DEL&dest=MAA